# Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. when installing vuepy

Tags: python, vue.js, pip, python-wheel

trying to install vuepy with `pip install vuepy` and getting the error above.
my `pip` is up to date, `setuptools` and `wheel`s also.
what else can i try to do?
the full error is:

> C:\Users\XXXXX>pip install vuepy Collecting vuepy   Using cached
> vuepy-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (275 kB) Collecting brython==3.8.9 (from
> vuepy)   Using cached brython-3.8.9.tar.gz (1.2 MB)   Preparing
> metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting Jinja2~=2.10 (from vuepy)
> Using cached Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB) Collecting
> pyyaml~=5.1 (from vuepy)   Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build
> wheel ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   │
> exit code: 1   ╰─> [62 lines of output]
> C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
> !!
>
> ```
>           ********************************************************************************
>           The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
>
>           This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
>           calls to avoid build errors in the future.
>
>           See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
> ```
>
> for details.
> ********************************************************************************
>
> ```
>   !!
>     parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
>   running egg_info
>   writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>   writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>   writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
> ```
>
> line 353, in 
> main()
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py",
> line 335, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py",
> line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return hook(config_settings)
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
> line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
> line 325, in *get_build_requires
> self.run_setup()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
> line 341, in run_setup
> exec(code, locals())
> File "", line 271, in 
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init**.py", line 103, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py",
> line 185, in setup
> return run_commands(dist)
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py",
> line 201, in run_commands
> dist.run_commands()
> File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py",
> line 969, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
> line 989, in run_command
> super().run_command(command)
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py",
> line 988, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py",
> line 318, in run
> self.find_sources()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py",
> line 326, in find_sources
> mm.run()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py",
> line 548, in run
> self.add_defaults()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py",
> line 586, in add_defaults
> sdist.add_defaults(self)
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py",
> line 113, in add_defaults
> super().add_defaults()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\sdist.py",
> line 251, in add_defaults
> self._add_defaults_ext()
> File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\sdist.py",
> line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
> self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
> File "", line 201, in get_source_files
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-69wqwgg9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(attr)
> AttributeError: cython_sources
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit
> code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+cython_sources

Comment: As `vuepy` requires `PyYAML<6.0` it can only be installed with `pip install --no-build-isolation vuepy`. Works for me. Please report the bug at https://github.com/stefanhoelzl/vue.py/issues